# Recycle App Pool Programmatically in IIS 10 / Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, windows-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to create a function that will allow a user to reset/recycle an application pool on demand in order to reload updated IIS site settings, however I'm running into a permissions issue anytime I try to use a ServerManager function.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[site_list.SelectedValue];
if (appPool != null) {
    if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Stopped) {
        appPool.Start();
    } else {
        appPool.Recycle();
    }
}
```

Any time I run the code, I get the following error:

> Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due
>   to insufficient permissions
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Filename:
>   redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to
>   insufficient permissions
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.

I've tried granting read permissions to the redirection.config file to any/all of the following users with no change:

- ASPNET
- NETWORK SERVICE
- IUSR
- IIS_IUSRS

Anyone happen to have any insight on how to recycle an AppPool through code?

Answer (score 0):

I can get it work when I set application pool identity to **LocalSystem** and anonymous authentication->Edit->Use application pool identity.

[image]

[image]
[image]

I think if you don't want to use LocalSystem, then you have to grant special permission for C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config folder and your application root folder. It will also reduce the security of your computer.

Microsoft Process monitor could help you grant NTFS permission. You could add a filter for "process name=w3wp.exe" and "result=access denied".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon